# Private CocoaPod Spec with Dependency Cannot Find Dependency

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, dependency-management

I'm trying to deploy a private CocoaPod, and I'm running into a perplexing issue with my framework's dependency graph. I cannot get my code to find a necessary class from one of its dependencies - RestKit, to be specific.

I first ran `pod lib create` to create the framework, then added RestKit as a dependency of the private CocoaPod in its `.podpsec` file. Everything seemed to be working fine until I referenced one particular class in RestKit, which it cannot seem to find unless I use an `@import` statement.

I've tried all of the following include's, and none of them work:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/ObjectMapping.h>
#import <RestKit.h>
#import <ObjectMapping.h>
#import "RestKit.h"
#import "ObjectMapping.h"
```

The only one that does work is `@import RestKit.ObjectMapping`. However, using this import/include statement causes `pod lib lint` to fail as it can't find RestKit. I'm a bit stuck as to what else to try here. I've remade the podspec project already, and I've tried all the includes. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

## Edit:

Below is my podspec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    s.name             = "MyAPI"
    s.version          = "0.1.4"
    s.summary          = "My summary here."

    s.description      = <<-DESC
                        My description here.
                       DESC

    s.homepage         = "http://example.com"

    s.license          = 'None'
    s.author           = { "Sean Olszewski" => "sean@somewebsite.com" }
    s.source           = { :git => "ssh://username@myprivateserver/path/to/private/pod/repo", :tag => s.version.to_s }


    s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
    s.requires_arc = true

    s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
    s.resource_bundles = {
        'MyAPI' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
    }

    s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
    s.dependency 'RestKit', '~> 0.25.0'
    s.dependency 'RKValueTransformers'

end
```

Comment: Could you post your Podspec ?

Comment: Just added it @Loegic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a `version` and a `development target` for your `Pod`.

```
s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
s.platform = :ios, '7.0'
```

Also you will have to change the import statement in your code, as it will be interpreted as a `module` (`use_frameworks!` in the `pod file` ), that's why you can't use `#import` anymore.

If you run into the '`non modular include`' you will the to set the property in your `Podspec`:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far Loegic. I tried what you said, ran `pod update` after updating my pod spec, and then switched the `@import` to `#import` and still ran into the same issue. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you pod spec lint you pod spec, what does it says ? Because pod update will update what you wrote in your Podfile file not in the pod spec file

Comment: I should also note that I have to enable "Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules" for RestKit to compile properly.

Comment: You can see the error log here: https://gist.github.com/srosmd/6517e1e82330730519c0
.
 If I run `pod spec lint --allow-warnings --use-libraries` I get this:
https://gist.github.com/srosmd/806b5f29ba1f8b66b773

Comment: You should add core.xcconfig = { 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES'} to your podspec

Comment: In adding that line to my podspec, I was able to get it to pass validation (Great success!) but now when I run my tests in the workspace file, they silently fail. The only issues that are reported in Xcode are two warnings that are safe to ignore from AFNetworking.

Comment: Don't forget to import the pod in your project. Maybe a pod disintegrate, then pod install will do it

Comment: Thanks for all your help Loegic - I've gotten it working now! The silently failing error was due to an `@import` in my test's prefix header that shouldn't have been there.